import class in admin.py from package that in site-packages
I used django-comment-system
I want import classadmin from admin.py (that in my app project) at admin.py (that in LIB/site-packages/comment)
from kernel.blog import models #here is LIB/site-packages/comment/admin.py

i tried with that code but give me error:
No module named 'kernel.blog'
kernel is base and blog is a app in kernel

That import location corresponds to comment.admin, as the default mapping to package namespaces and modules in Python is from the underlying names of the directories and files.
